# OpenCart карточки товара

Tags: opencart

Есть карточки товары, в каждой карточке есть 2 фото. Одно основное, второе по наведению показывается. Почему-то сейчас основной выводится как раз вторая фотка. Хотя в админке задаю порядок вывода. В чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: В чём угодно. Думаете без вашего кода можно что-то сказать определённее? Вопрос следует закрыть, так как отсутствует код, необходимый для минимального воспроизведения проблемы.

Comment: поменяйте порядок вывода и ппц.